# How can I serialize a Dictionary<string, object> to javascript?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dictionary

This is my code :

```
public class PuntoMappa
{
    string Lat;
    string Lng;

    public PuntoMappa(string Lat, string Lng)
    {
        this.Lat = Lat;
        this.Lng = Lng;
    }
}   

PuntiCategoriaMappa.Add("1111", new PuntoMappa("1", "2"));
PuntiCategoriaMappa.Add("2222", new PuntoMappa("3", "4"));
PuntiCategoriaMappa.Add("3333", new PuntoMappa("5", "6"));

var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "PuntiCategoriaMappa", "PuntiCategoriaMappa = " + jsonSerializer.Serialize(PuntiCategoriaMappa) + ";", true);
```

but the serialization is :

```
PuntiCategoriaMappa = {"1111":{},"2222":{},"3333":{}};
```

Well, I lost the serialization of `PuntoMappa` objects.

How can I correctly do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make the Lat and Lng publicly accessible.

```
public class PuntoMappa
{
    public string Lat { get; private set; }
    public string Lng { get; private set; }

    public PuntoMappa(string Lat, string Lng)
    {
        this.Lat = Lat;
        this.Lng = Lng;
    }
}
```